# Name of the Armenian people/language

Tags: pronunciation, names, armenian

I once knew an Armenian girl from Yerevan and she said the Armenian people are the Hy (pronounced like "Hi, how are you") and their language is Hy-idan. However, the wikipedia writes the name of the language as "hayeren". What explains the discrepancy?

Comment: Armenian has its own alphabet. Different people trying to transcribe the foreign sounds of a foreign language into an alphabet designed for another language are likely to do so differently if each is not aware of and trying to follow a specified standard.

Comment: Presumably what you've written as <d> in your 'Hy-idan' is actually either a tap (or maybe the trill, they contrast in Armenian) which is normally rendered as <r> when writing Armenian in the Roman alphabet.

Answer (score 5):

“Armenian” is հայերեն for which the usual transliteration is hayeren. ր is a single-tap /r/, as opposed to the trilled ռ, transliterated as ṙ.